# What C++ IDE / approach would you recommend me?

Tags: c++, ide, cross-platform

I know this question has been asked countless times before, but the other threads appear to be rather old, so I decided to make a new one.

Im starting my bachelor thesis in november and am writing a programm in C++ for that. The program will be available on Linux and Windows (possibly Mac) so ideally Ill just have to recompile my code.

How would you recommend me to play it? Develop it fully under one OS first, and then try to compile it on another and hope there is very little compiler-dependant code or should I check throughout the development if my code is portable enough?

And, what IDE should I use? Im looking to use Qt and maybe Boost or some other library, should the need arise. 
Ive got acsess to Visual Studio 2010. I also tried CodeLite and liked that a lot, except the debugger, which I thought was very unfriendly and SVN, which I also didn't figure out back then. I used Eclipse CDT, mainly for the debugger and SVN, because I worked a lot with Eclipse for Java, but still preferred CodeLite "overall".
Or should I use Qt SDK?

Which of those would you think suit best in my case?

- VS10 - Develop everything here, then "port" to Linux
- Eclipse CDT
- CodeLite (any recommedable plugins?)
- Qt SDK
- Some other? (SVN support is important)

Thanks

Evgeni

Comment: Develop on Windows and then port to Linux is definitely the wrong way. If you do it the other way around you will have much much less work to do. Plus if you choose Qt, you won't have to port anything, just recompile.

Comment: write portable code in standard C++, any functionality not available in the standard libraries, use a portable library (as you've already figured out). Your design should be of higher importance than which IDE you use... get your priorities right..

Comment: Dude, for Qt you use Qt Creator. Windows? Uninstall.

Comment: What exactly are you implementing it for? What kind of system calls will it require (as this is where it really gets complicated and differs a lot between OSes)?

Comment: @Vlad Unfortunatly, I kinda have to suporrt Windows, as this program should be a turing mashine simulator which will be used by math students as well

Comment: @RedX A Turing machine simulator. I don't expect it to have any system calls, just the libraries (Qt and Boost). It will also have a LaTeX output option, so I dont see where real incompatibilities should arise. I only worry about compiler dependent code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to port, make sure your code compiles on all relevant platforms at each milestone. Don't expect to easily retrofit compatibility at the end!

Qt is great. So is CMake, which generates a build environment for various platforms; it's also SVN-friendly.

I generally avoid Mircosoft but Visual Studio has great integration and debugging, just make sure your code doesn't depend on it (derive the VS project from CMake and keep it separate from the source in SVN).

Qt Creator is great if your project is strongly a Qt project. If you are using Qt simply to have a UI/network/foo library -- any UI/network/foo library -- then you might be happier with something which is stronger in other aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Portable and Qt? I'd go for [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).